# Jew with non-Jewish father: maternal grandfather has no Hebrew name; great-grandfather's Hebrew name unknown

Tags: names, torah-service, family-members

Usually, when a Jew's father is not a Jew, the name of the maternal grandfather is used when being called up to Torah. (Source?) But what happens if the maternal grandfather does not have a Hebrew name, and the name of the maternal great-grandfather is not known? Would you use the mother's name? Let's also suppose that the grandfather is deceased and cannot be asked for a Hebrew name.

Comment: I would say that the logic is the same as a father with no Hebrew name.

Comment: @sabbahillel - That is definitely not the same question. I asked that one.

Comment: @ezra Maybe you can edit to explain why they’re different? As it stands, I tend to agree with sabbahillel that they’re dupes, but I’m willing to hold off my VTC until you explain.

Comment: I don't see how it's a duplicate. That asks about a _mi sheberach_ and this asks about calling someone up to the _Tora_.

Comment: Second @msh210  and voting to reopen for this reason.

Comment: The source of calling up this person "Ploni ben his grandfather's name" can be find in Shulchan Aruch Siman 139 seif 3 in the Rema. Look also in Mishna Berura on this very source

Answer (score 0):

We can also call that person with the name of his mother instead. I have seen this several times.

Comment: Do you have a source, maybe?

Comment: You can also call him up by his legal English name. You don't even need to call him up by name at all. Just say "you, come on up".

Comment: @DoubleAA, יעמד ששי

Comment: My local orthodox rabbis for instance as a source. Also I saw some people in this case called "...son of Abraham" even if the father is not Jewish. Some communities called up people by their mother's name, some other communities mentioned the father's name, rarely with both parents names in the orthodox world.